# How can you scroll in the Assistant Editor horizontally or vertically?

Tags: xcode, ios8

Is there a scrollbar to allow horizontal/vertical scrolling in the Assistant Editor preview in Xcode 6?

I know you can zoom in and zoom out but when zoomed out you can only view no more than one device at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As i know theres no scroll bar
Horizontal srcolling:
but you can try

horizontal scrolling:

**(shift + scrollMouseWheel up\downslide)**

Vertical scrolling:

**(scrollMouseWheel up\downslide)**

Set active window on preview. (tested on Xcode 6.3)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the scrolling, but if you want to view multiple devices in preview best way is to open preview up in a separate window, works very nicely and beats running on your project on 3 different simulators evertime you make a change....see a great tutorial [here](http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/09/27/maximizing-the-preview-assistant-editor-in-xcode-6/)